# How to see if a object is inside of 4 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

(i am asking this again)
Hello there guys, I am having a bit of a problem, basically i made this simple script that detect if the blue diamond is inside of the four spheres (see image below), and it works pretty good, but however I don't know how to make it so that when you rotate the four spheres 90 degrees, it still detects if it is inside, I think that I must use TransformDirection, but I don't know where to implement it, here is the script: https://hastebin.com/perevejoku.cs

here is a little visual of what I am talking about :
[image]
And here is what i mean when i say rotated :
[image]
I think this can help me, but I don't know how to implement it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle

Comment: What do you mean by **rotate the four spheres 90 degrees**. Rotate them from their origin? Rotate them from the midPoint(Blue Diamond). Can you provide an image for that also?

Comment: sorry, i forgot about that, there i updated the image so you can see @Thalthanas

Comment: It's still hard to grasp from the image for me at least, but you need the blue diamond to be inside of the spheres and needs to face a direction for your condition to become successful? Or the blue diamond just needs to be in the midpoint of the spheres?

Comment: @Thalthanas  well i want for the script to detect if the blue diamond is somewhere inside of the four spheres (https://imgur.com/a/0nbUz) and i made a simple script that does that,(https://hastebin.com/perevejoku.cs) however when you rotate it, like in the picture, it doesn't work, it just detects if the blue sphere is on the same X axis, when it should detect if it's on the Z Axis, since it is rotated

Comment: Seems more clear now. If the spheres are in fixed position, like a square in your case (rotation does not matter), however you rotate it, the square shape will stay same. So you can use colliders. Add an empty gameObject as a child to one of the spheres and add a box collider to it. Adjust its property so the collider will cover the area between the spheres. After that you can check it with `OnCollisionEnter()` or `OnTriggerEnter()` if the diamond is in the area or not.

Comment: @Thalthanas well that could work, but The diamond can't have a script, (since i plan on doing this with vertices) so I don't know how to check for other objects

Comment: Diamond does not need to have a script for this scenario, you can check it from collider like `if(other.gameObject.tag=="Diamond")` but if you want to do this with vertices, I am out of ideas rn.

Comment: Maybe you should convert the world positions to screenspace, so you don't have to worry about the 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decompose vector **AP** in basis of **AB**, **AC** and **ABxAC** (cross product) vectors where P is diamond coordinates, B,A,C are three neighbor spheres.

If coordinates t,u,w in that basis fulfill such conditions:

```
 t in range 0..1
 u in range 0..1
 w is 0
```

then point P lies in the plane of rectangle formed by spheres and lies in rectangle limits.

```
AP.x = P.x - A.x //same for y,z
//same for AB, AC
Normal = CrossProduct(AB, AC)

system of linear equation for unknowns t,u,w:
t * AB.x + u * AC.x + w * N.x = AP.x
t * AB.y + u * AC.y + w * N.y = AP.y
t * AB.z + u * AC.z + w * N.z = AP.z
```

Comment: I don't really understand that much about this, could you provide a simpler explanation or some basic code to work off?

Comment: If you are going to deal with 2D or 3D graphics, this is the time to learn about vector algebra. I gave some basic formulas, but I am sure that Unity contains functions for vector subtracting, cross product and so on.

Comment: @Sinci1 I recommend [3Blue1Brown Essence of linear algebra videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjBOesZCoqc&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab)